# CuDNN6 on Nvidia TX2

Tags: nvidia, cudnn

I am trying to follow: https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installTensorFlowTX2
to install tensorflow on my TX2. After `./setTensorFlowEV.sh` I get the following error:

```
Invalid path to cuDNN  toolkit. Neither of the following two files can be found:
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib64/libcudnn.so.6.0.21
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.6.0.21
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.6.0.21
```

This suggest I do not have cudnn6 installed on my TX2. Since tx2 is aarch64 and not x86 I am a bit stuck as nvidia only provides binary for x86 etc and not for aarch64. I understand I can flash my device with newest jetpack to get the cudnn.

Is there any other simpler way (without flashing my device) to install cudnn6 on tx2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JetPack to install cuDNN without flashing the device. Just

1. open JetPack, click `next` until you reach the screen showing all the available packages and set everything to `no action`
2. select cuDNN, set it to `install` and click `next`
3. A screen will show up asking you for the ip, username and password of your Jetson. Fill that out and click `next`
4. JetPack will now SSH into your Jetson and install cuDNN for you